# Is it possible to get name or ID of the view in OOB lookup dialog window in CRM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to get the name or ID of the Look in view in the OOB Lookup window in CRM.

Let me explain the situation. I have a lookup dialog window on the button. When the button is clicked, this window opens up. By default, the view shows only filtered records because I used filter criteria In URL.

But when I  do change the Look in view, it shows the same filtered result which is not correct.  How it can be implemented. 
Here is my code;

```
 var url = serverurl + "/_controls/lookup/lookupinfo.aspx?AllowFilterOff=0&DefaultType=" + Xrm.Internal.getEntityCode('p15_inquiries') + "&DisableQuickFind=0&DisableViewPicker=0&IsInlineMultiLookup=0&IsTypeUnresolved=1&LookupStyle=multi&ShowNewButton=1&ShowPropButton=1&browse=false&currentObjectType=10017&currentid=%7b" + bookingId + "%7d&dType=1&isRegardingFieldPopulated=false&mrsh=false&objecttypes=" + Xrm.Internal.getEntityCode('p15_inquiries') + "";
        var someFetchXml = '<filter type="and"><condition attribute="p15_contactinquiriesid" operator="eq" value="' + contactId +'"/></filter>';
        var filter = "&customFilter=" + CrmEncodeDecode.CrmUrlEncode(CrmEncodeDecode.CrmUrlEncode(someFetchXml)) + "&customFilterTypes=";
        url = url + filter;

 var dialogwindow = new parent.Mscrm.CrmDialog(Mscrm.CrmUri.create(url), window, 550, 550);
        dialogwindow.setCallbackReference(function (result){
});
dialogwindow.show();
```

Comment: if I understand you want, if view is changed your custom filter should not work and should show data as per view is that correct?

Comment: what did you endup with?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing unsupported stuff. As you may aware - It's not recommended.

Also what you wanted to achieve is not the global intended behavior - we always wanted to stick with the applied filter across views. Moreover we cannot hookup the `onChange` event of "Look in" view dropdown to identify & remove the applied filter. If your requirement is unique - then its recommended to develop your own HTML web resource to mimic lookup window & implement the logic. Otherwise identify the necessity & decide before clicking the custom button & filter will be added based on that.

Btw, lookup customizations has evolved a lot, CRM versions too - still you are stuck in 2011? We can do `addPreSearch` and `addCustomFilter` to adjust the filter. But still cannot be changed `onChange` of dropdowns in lookup popup. [Read more](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathaneccles/2013/09/30/crm-2013-javascript-lookup-filtering-using-addcustomfilter)

I don't have CRM 2011 to verify - but you should try `addCustomView` option.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(primContactFieldName).addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
```

[Reference](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/08/05/creating-custom-filtered-lookup-crm-2011/)